# Is Not Installed (Residual config) safe to remove all?

Tags: package-management

In Synaptic Manager I noticed I had a lot of packages in that list, and was wondering if any shouldn't be removed for some reason? Or if that is all safe to be removed. Is it possible that some should be kept, or does that show useless packages that should be cleared?

I have ran `sudo apt-get autoremove`  but they are still there. (Also clean & autoclean)

[image: What it is...]

Comment: FYI—these configuration files do not take up a lot of space.  I just purged 342 packages with residual config files (mostly old kernels) and the grand total of reclaimed disk space: 2.6 MiB.

Comment: @hackel Linux kernel residual config takes up lots of space

Comment: @hackel FWIW I just had an outage exactly because these configuration files took enough space to fill root

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Those listed package are just those that have configuration files that hasn't been removed. Unless you are planning to reinstall the packages again, and want to keep the configuration, yes, you can remove them safely. In synaptic, you can purge  them by selecting them all, use the Package menu, then Purge. You can do this from the terminal too:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get purge
```

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 18.04 this does not work. However, it works if i add `--yes` option to the last command: `xargs sudo apt-get --yes purge`. Or else if i replace it with `xargs sudo dpkg --purge`.

Answer (score 63):

<sup>As [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/539358/256099) question merged to here, there is need to provide some information which may helpful</sup>

From `man apt-get`:

```
       remove
           remove is identical to install except that packages are removed instead of installed. Note
           that removing a package leaves its configuration files on the system. If a plus sign is
           appended to the package name (with no intervening space), the identified package will be
           installed instead of removed.

       purge
           purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration
           files are deleted too).
```

**So, when you remove package(s) usually by using Ubuntu-Software-Center or by `sudo apt-get remove`, it leaves its configuration files on system.**

From [community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Removal_commands),

> While there is no built in way to remove all of your configuration information from your removed packages you can remove all configuration data from every removed package with the following command.
>
> ```
> dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge
> ```

**So, Run following command from terminal:**

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs dpkg --purge
```

This will removes configuration files from removed package.

Comment: this also: `dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get --purge remove -y`

Answer (score 1):

Another simple answer is with `dpkg --get-selections`.

`dpkg --get-selections | grep 'deinstall$' | cut -f1 | xargs sudo apt --yes purge`

`dpkg --get-selections` will briefly list packages, `grep 'deinstall$'` will select only those with configuration files left, without `--yes` the command will ask for confirmation but will not wait for user input(GNOME Terminal 3.48.1) and will terminate without doing anything.

Comment: Or you can use `xargs -o` (`-o` or `--open-tty`), which will open the TTY so that `apt` can ask for confirmation.