# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, gtk

I am using Xubuntu 14.04 (Ubuntu + `xubuntu-desktop`), The following Message shown many times (such as executing `mousepad` , `zenity` etc).

```
$ mousepad
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ zenity --info
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
```

Why I am getting this message? How to solve?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After installing `xubuntu-desktop`, I've removed some packages that are pre-installed in Ubuntu 14.04 (and no longer required) by [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8610758/) command.

These packages removed successfully and all working fine but some **residual config** are still exist and hence I removed **`unity-scrollbar`** from **synaptic** residual config:

[image]

Which removed files like: **`/etc/X11/Xsession.d/81overlay-scrollbar`**.

After logout and login I again tried to launch by command as below:

```
$ mousepad
$ zenity --info
```

Now `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"` is gone, and problem solved.

Comment: For clearing all residual config, Visit : http://askubuntu.com/a/540173/256099

Comment: I just manually removed /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81overlay-scrollbar and relogged.  The warning went away.  Thanks.

Comment: This is an another correct way to clean-up the residual configuration: `sudo dpkg --purge overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:amd64 overlay-scrollbar-gtk3:amd64`

Comment: BTW, technically, the message is related to the `GTK_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar` environment variable that is set in the `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/81overlay-scrollbar` file.

Comment: But how did you associate the error message with the residual package? That is a mystery to me!

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall overlay-scrollbar-gtk2
```

Fixed this for me.

It reinstalls

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/liboverlay-scrollbar.so
```

which was missing before.