# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar" Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gtk, qt-creator, overlay-scrollbars

I run application in reinstalled Qt Creator 3.5.1 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 32 bit)
And the building is successful.
But also there are warnings:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
(untitled01:20644): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(untitled01:20644): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538993/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-overlay-scrollbar) solution doesn't help
and `sudo apt-get autoremove`too

[Another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66356/gdk-gtk-warnings-and-errors-from-the-command-line) solution talks about  `gtk2-engines-pixbuf` package
but what about gtk3?

Do you know some correct idea?

Answer (score 19):

In my computer with Ubuntu 16.04, I solved it installing the package `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall overlay-scrollbar-gtk2
```

Comment: Worked for me, Ubuntu 18.04 64bit.

Comment: Solved the overlay-scrollbar failure message for me, Ubuntu 18.04 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

You have three options here:

- Ignore the warnings
- Remove overlay-scrollbar stuff

  ```
  #Step 1
  echo "export GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0" >> ~/.profile

  #Step 2
  mkdir -p ~/.config/gtk-3.0
  cat <<EOF > ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
  /* Adding the buttons on the edges (if you don't need them, skip the next 4 lines)
   */

  .scrollbar {
    -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
    -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
  }

  /* Scrollbar trough squeezes when cursor hovers over it. Disabling that
   */

  .scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(ltr),
  .scrollbar.vertical.dragging:dir(ltr) {
      margin-left: 0px;
  }

  .scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(rtl),
  .scrollbar.vertical.dragging:dir(rtl) {
      margin-right: 0px;
  }

  .scrollbar.horizontal:hover,
  .scrollbar.horizontal.dragging,
  .scrollbar.horizontal.slider:hover,
  .scrollbar.horizontal.slider.dragging {
      margin-top: 0px;
  }

  /* Slider widens to fill the scrollbar when cursor hovers over it. Making it permanent
   */

  .scrollbar.slider.vertical:dir(ltr):not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
      margin-left: 0px;
  }

  .scrollbar.slider.vertical:dir(rtl):not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
      margin-right: 0px;
  }

  .scrollbar.slider.horizontal:not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
      margin-top: 0px;
  }

  EOF

  #Step 3
  cat <<EOF > ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
  [Settings]
  gtk-color-scheme="tooltip_bg_color:#ffffaf\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000"
  gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=0

  gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false

  EOF

  #Step 4
  sudo apt-get purge overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2
  ```
- Reinstall overlay-scrollbar stuff

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2
  ```

Comment: I tried to reinstall overlay-scrollbar, but terminal said:
`E: Unable to locate package overlay-scrollbar-gtk2
`
Then to remove overlay-scrollbar stuff with your steps.
And  now the errors come again without first line
`Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar`

Comment: Do you read my answer correctly? I present three variants (logical "OR").

Comment: Yep.
And I tried all of them (exception is first)

Answer (score 1):

on 64bit LTS18.04,  `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2` did not get rid of the gtk-message `Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar` while `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386` did the job, that is:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386
```