# Inkscape stopped working after mate replaced Ubuntu

Tags: mate

I had a pc with Ubuntu on it and it now has Ubuntu mate. This apparently caused changes to my system and when I tried to launch inkscape I got this error:

> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
>   Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
>   Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
>
> (inkscape:10640): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :19.0

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall inkscape via snap and via Software (I am not sure which software manager mate uses).

Also, have followed the proposed solutions in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984556/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-overlay-scrollbar-ubuntu-17-10) but to no avail.

Is there something else I can try to make inkscape launchable again?

Edit:
This seems odd, but I also tried [these solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548557/how-to-install-gail-and-atk-bridge) and they don't seem to either remove the other error messages.

Edit 2:
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with mate desktop added on top.

I have run the commands mentioned in the comment from how is inkscape installed:

```
$dpkg -l inkscape
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
+++-===============================-====================-====================-====================================================================
un  inkscape                        <none>               <none>               (no description available)
$ snap list | grep -i inkscape
inkscape            0.92.4                      7378  latest/stable     inkscape*     -
```

which is confusing to me at least. I thought that I would find inkscape installed by `dpkg` since the last attempt was with Software from mate. And although it's declared as installed in my list in the command above it appears corrupted(?). Maybe this is the reason I cannot execute it?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How did you installed Inkscape? What is the current source of Inkscape? Please add output of `which inkscape`, `dpkg -l inkscape`, `snap list | grep -i inkscape` to the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `un` in output of `dpkg -l` means that it have the following queued actio

> `u` = Unknown

and state

> `n` = Not-installed

(see [`man dpkg-query`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) for details).

So I would recommend to remove snapped Inkscape and install APT-based instead:

```
snap remove inkscape

sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

Comment: ΟΚ, so the official way is nowadays by snap. And apart from a conflict for searching inkscape in snap folder (which does not exist) inkscape is back to life.