# purging a program

Tags: purge

I recently installed SDL2 and want to purge all of it from my system.

I know there's a million different libraries scattered all over the system.

anyway I can just uninstall everything without searching everywhere and pulling all kinds of files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you completely remove a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package) and [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably went on with terminal and typed something like:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

You can reverse the install of every install you make by editing the code:

`sudo apt-get remove libsdl2-dev` and purging it with --purge, then it looks like:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libsdl2-dev
```

Your terminal has a history, so every command you entered lately can be found by pressing the UP key, find what you installed and change the code to remove/purge it.

EDIT: Run the whole command in terminal to clean up.

```
echo "Cleaning Up" &&
sudo apt-get -f install &&
sudo apt-get autoremove &&
sudo apt-get -y autoclean &&
sudo apt-get -y clean
```

After that you can check the residual files in Synaptic Package Manager, 
referring you to this [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376253/is-not-installed-residual-config-safe-to-remove-all)

Comment: I installed from the source code.  How could I be sure to uninstall that? for example.  I did sudo apt-get remove --purge SDL2*, but obviously that left a bunch of stuff.  and I found directories with header files that I went and manually removed.  and then some lib files as well.  I still can use locate libSDL and it returns a slew of files, particularly libsdl2-image files I'm trying to remove.

Comment: I edited the answer, hopefully it helps you further.

Comment: Thanks.  I think it does.  I still see a bunch of files when I use locate in /doc/ and /var/.  I'm guessing these aren't things I should be touching?

Comment: If you ran the code I posted in my answer, then yes, delete them.
Those are dependencies and unused files and are safe to remove. If you open Synaptic Package manager and go to tab "Status" you will probably see the same files, which are residual unused dependencies. Purge them all ;)