# Where is apache2.conf in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I am trying to install amp on ubuntu using this tutorial.
[How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)

On the apache part of the tutorial it says the following:
*Set Global ServerName to Suppress Syntax Warnings
Next, we will add a single line to the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file to suppress a warning message.* 
I can't find such a directory on the system. I have installed apache, but can't find any file of the sort.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please check if apache is installed properly. Run below command to check if that installed. dpkg -l | grep apache

Comment: Here is a picture of it http://imgur.com/a/Jg9Fa I tried formatting it but it didn't show correctly. Sorry

Comment: Generally if it does not exist your create the file.

Comment: Here you are the default content of [`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25131365/) from Ubuntu 16.04. To suppress the above warning message, you need to add the directive `ServerName localhost` at the bottom of the file (or change localhost with some concrete FDQN). Just type `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, paste the conten of the above link by `shift+insert`, save and exit by `ctrl+o`/`ctrl+x`. Then restart Apache: `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`. Could you edit your question with the output of `ls -l /etc/apache2/`?

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen yesterday to a friend's laptop.

If you had installed apache or related software using any unsupported PPAs,
remove them using `ppa-purge`:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:whatever/ppa
```

Remove apache2 and unused dependencies:

```
sudo apt autoremove apache2
```

Remove residual configuration files:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get purge
```

(Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/376281)

Now install apache again:

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

This worked in bionic.