# Command line to get rid of "residual config"

Tags: command-line, apt, synaptic, aptitude

After I install a new kernel and do `sudo apt autoremove` these two items related to the just-removed kernel always show up in `synaptic` under *Not Installed (residual config)*.

[image]

What's the terminal command to get rid of these, so I don't have to open `synaptic`?  Can I do it through `aptitude`?

Comment: Dupe of https://askubuntu.com/q/855755/527350?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/376253/is-not-installed-residual-config-safe-to-remove-all